# Pandas converts int values to float in dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, floating-point

I wrote a script that takes a csv file as an input, manipulates the data by using pandas and creates another csv file.

Everything is OK, however pandas converts integer values to double by default.
e.g.

in csv before:

```
5f684ee8-7398-914d-9d87-7b44c37ef081,France,44,72000,No,isBool("true")
```

in csv after:

```
E84E685F-9873-4D91-9D87-7B44C37EF081,France,44.0,72000.0,No,True
```

Here 44 and 72000 are changed to 44.0 and 72000.0

I know how to turn them into int using apply() in dataframe, however this script is going to be generic and I am looking to configure pandas at first.

Basically, I expect pandas not to put .0 if it is not a floating number.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems in columns are some `NaN` values, so `int` is cast to `float`

Comment: check it by `df[df['col'].isnull()]` and possible solution is replaced `NaN` to some scalar like `0` - `df[['col', 'col1']] = df[['col', 'col1']].fillna()`

Comment: Have you tried to set the float_format argument of pandas.DataFrame.to_csv according to your requirements?? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html It seems to be it does what you want

Comment: Yes I've just tried that and this time it converted my floating point 44.89 to 45..

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, some operations in pandas can change dtypes. see for exemple [this page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na).

A solution can be :

```
df.to_csv(float_format="%.0f")
```

which round every (false) float to an integer format.

An exemple :

```
In [355]: pd.DataFrame(columns=list(range(6)), 
data=[['E84E685F-9873-4D91-9D87-7B44C37EF081', 'France', 44.0, 72000, 'No', True]]
).to_csv(float_format='%.f')
Out[355]: ',0,1,2,3,4,5\n0,E84E685F-9873-4D91-9D87-7B44C37EF081,France,44,72000,No,True\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but when I add float_format argument, this time pandas rounds my floats (e.g. 44.89 to 45) which I don't want.

Comment: Do you have any solution yet?

Comment: It doesnt work: `gav['steam_appid'].to_csv('../data/F.csv', sep=';',index=False,  float_format="%.10g" )`

Comment: Is it possible to apply the `float_format` to a specified set of columns? I have both `int` and `float` in my df, and I want that only some floats cols to be converted to int...

Answer (score 2):

Similar to B. M.'s answer, you can parse your floats like the following:

```py
df.to_csv(float_format="%.10g")
```

This will force numbers to be written without exponent if they have a precision of at most 10 digits. so 2,147,483,647 will render as `2147483647` and 10<sup>-2</sup> will render as `0.01`. You will run into issues if you have big integers (bigger than 10 digits) as these will be rendered as exponents instead.